# Найти по собственному атрибуту и добавить css стиль?

Tags: jquery, css

Всем привет. Есть ссылки:

```
<a rel="telefony1" href="#">Телефоны1</a>
<a rel="telefony2" href="#">Телефоны2</a>
<a rel="telefony3" href="#">Телефоны3</a>
<a rel="telefony4" href="#">Телефоны4</a>
```

У этих ссылок есть собственный атрибут rel.

При каждом клике на страницу у меня есть переменная c разными значениями telefony1, telefony2, telefony3 или telefony4.

Как мне найти ссылку с атрибутом rel равной переменной и присвоить ей какой-нибудь css.

Например, если переменная равна telefony2, я нахожу telefony2  и присваиваю ей какое-нибудь css свойство.

Comment: может вам стоит документацию почитать?

    $('a[rel="' + ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ +'"]').css({});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var selector = '[rel="telefony%d"]'.replace('%d', number)
$(selector);
```